What is the recommened way to re-use assets from a dependency that is installed via composer?
I am new to composer in the PHP world.
I am trying to create a package Foo that has the package Bar as a dependency. Bar is available via packagist. Foo doesn't need any of the PHP code of Bar though, just some of the assets. These assets can change with every new release of Bar, so it's not really feasible to ship them with Foo.
Foo is not supposed to run on its own (although it could), but it's supposed to be used as a dependency by other packages - for instance Yada. That is where my trouble begins.
So, let's say, we have

Bar with some assets.
Foo using Bar as a dependency, e.g. with a composer.json where the relevant pieces look like

{
  "name": "foo/foo",
  "require": {
    "bar/bar": "<some-version>"
  }
}


Yada using Foo as a dependency, e.g. with a composer.json where the relevant pieces look like

{
  "name": "yada/yada",
  "require": {
    "foo/foo": "<some-version>"
  }
}

I tried installing Foo on its own (in theory one could create a tool from that which could be useful standalone) and as a dependency of Bar. I expected vendor folder to always be created in the same spot (relative to my Foo files).
But:

If I run composer install on Foo directly, then vendor/Bar will be put into Foo's directory.
If I run composer install on Yada, then Foo and Bar will both be installed, but vendor/Foo and vendor/Bar will be put into Yada's folder, so Bar's files will be in a different spot compared to 1).
Please note that 1) does not mean I have run composer install on Yada, changed into the vendor/Foo and there ran composer install again.

That means, that I cannot know where the assets that I want to used will be placed in relation to the files of Foo, can I? In other words: How would a PHP class of Foo know where too look for the vendor files of Bar that contain the assets if Foo was installed as a dependency (or sub-depencency or sub-sub-...) of some other package?
I learned about the post-install-cmd script that you can add to the composer.json file. That would allow me to copy the assets to a pre-determined folder in relation to the files of Foo, so they could be referenced. Alas, "Only scripts defined in the root package's composer.json are executed. If a dependency of the root package specifies its own scripts, Composer does not execute those additional scripts.". In other words, when you install Foo as a dependency of Yada, then the post-install-cmd script will not run.
Is there a recommended solution to this kind of problem in the "composer world"? Or would it mean that when you want to use Foo in your package, you will not only have to add it using require in your composer.json, but to also add a tiny post-install-cmd script to copy/move the asset files as required? Would this be considered acceptable for PHP projects?

When installing dependencies, you should always install them from the project folder, not from any other dependency. vendor/Bar will always be in that same location. Never run any commands in the vendor folder by hand

@NicoHaase Thanks for your reply! Then maybe my description is not clear: I didn't run any commands in the vendor folder manually.

How did you get files in Foo's directory otherwise?

@NicoHaase Please see my revised information. Case 1) did not describe using composer install on Yada, then changing into vendor/Foo and running composer install. Case 1) described simply starting fresh with Foo, e.g. by cloning the repository and then running composer install. This is not pointless, as it could in theory become a useful tool of it's own, too. My question is: How would a PHP class of Foo know where too look for the vendor files of Bar that contain the assets if Foo was installed as a dependency (or sub-depencency or sub-sub-...) of some other package?

Doesn't Bar's code provide you with methods to extract its assets? Or are you leeching files out of the repo without using any of its functionality?

@AlexHowansky It's not meant to be used for it's assets only, so it doesn't provide any special methods for that.

Bar will always be under ./vendor/bar, relative to the composer.json that required it. The only thing you need to determine is the project root, which you could require the caller to inject, or ask Composer to provide.
For example, in Foo, you can use Composer itself to determine Bar's install directory:
composer require composer/composer

And then:
$barPath = (new \Composer\InstalledVersions())->getInstallPath('bar/bar');

This will give you the correct directory regardless of whether Bar is running from Foo or from Yada. (Which you'll then presumably have to manipulate further to get to the assets.)

I don't know whether this is recommended, but I was able to find a solution to my problem:
Given that I don't think I can determine where in the dependency chain Foo will be in relation to Bar - given that it could be used as a dependency or potentially standalone at some point - I created a simple function to traverse the file tree upwards starting at __DIR__ looking for vendor.

I would not recommend this, as: 1) it's not necessary because Bar is always going to be in the same place relative to the project root, 2) it requires multiple hits to disk, and 3) it will break if you happen to use a subdirectory called vendor for something else.

"I don't think I can determine" - why not? Foo is in vendor/foo, Bar is in vendor/bar

@NicoHaase Not if you use Foo standalone, which might be an option as I described. You will have `foo/vendor/bar' in that case.
